# Preloading/saving images from a url on build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

Im using react/next.js and a lot of the images are coming from a CMS in the form of a link - However this causes them to load really slowly (300ms+ even for 40kb images) so i want to prerender/preload/presave them every time on build.

Is there any way i can do this given the links to the images?